# Calling JS function on button in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a game where user can select if they want to play against their friend or against the computer

in my PHP file, I have created two buttons like this

```
<button id = "begin-game" onClick = "location.href='./g.php'" type = "button">START</button>
<button id = "begin-computer-game">Againts Ai</button>
```

The first button works as supposed but the second one doesn't. How do I call this method so when the user Clicks the button Against Ai it executes the following code

this is my code from js file

```
const game = new Game();
document.getElementById('begin-game').addEventListener('click', function() {
  game.startGame();
  document.getElementById('begin-computer-game').style.display = 'none';
  this.style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('play-area').style.opacity = '1';
});
document.getElementById('begin-computer-game').addEventListener('click', function() {
  game.startComputerGame();
  this.style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('begin-game').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('play-area').style.opacity = '1';
});
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  game.handleKeydown(event);
});
```

now I am getting this error [in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BspYB.png)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: have you placed javascript after the HTML elements ?

Comment: @Barmar I am not getting any errors in the console

Comment: @RakeshJakhar I have the JS code separated from my php file

Comment: @littleshon The point is whether the `<script>` tag that loads the JS file is before or after the `<body>`.

Comment: Try adding `console.log` statements to the functions, do you see the log messages?

Comment: @Barmar I tried console log and it prints me the message

Comment: That means the function is running. So the problem must be with `game.startComputerGame()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick`

> 1. addEventListener does not overwrite existing event handlers on elements, whereas onclick overrides any existing onclick = function event handlers.
> 2. addEventListener does not works in older versions of Internet Explorer ( > IE 9 ) which uses attachEvent instead ( < IE 9 ), whereas onclick works all the browsers.

```
<button id ="begin-computer-game" onclick ="functionA();">Againts Ai</button>
```

Your function

```
functionA(){
   game.startComputerGame();
   this.style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('begin-game').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('play-area').style.opacity = '1';
}
```

Comment: Why is this better than `addEventListener`?

Comment: @Barmar addEventListener does not overwrite existing event handlers on elements, whereas onclick overrides any existing onclick = function event handlers

Comment: The second button doesn't have an existing handler, so there's nothing to overwrite.

Comment: @Barmar what is the problem with onclick, why we can use that ?

Comment: [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is generally considered better.

Comment: Anyway, it's not clear why this would work when the original code doesn't. We should find out *why* the original code isn't working in the first place.

Comment: i tried to call the function onClick but again it doesn't work

Comment: @littleshon is there any error on console ? where you are including the JS ?

Comment: @RakeshJakhar there are no errors in the console and I have the JS in the separated file here in the php folder I have just included the sript

Comment: @littleshon put the file at end of the page, after the HTML elements

Comment: @RakeshJakhar I have updated the console.log error if you need the code to share let me know

Comment: @RakeshJakhar, why are you using `document.getElementById` ?

Comment: Where are the MDN references?

Comment: @nullptr I am using php